# How to create a link for QR code to avoid iOS from opening an app and instead open the browser

Tags: ios, iphone, url, qr-code

We have a mobile app foo.com
When someone with the mobile app on iOS tries to open a QR code with foo.com, i.e.,

https://webApp.foo.com/somepath?authToken

The mobile app opens and the user gets an error.

Android devices work fine even with the mobile app installed.

Is there a URL that would open the link in the browser without having to update the app or have users uninstall the mobile app?

Google Bard indicated that a schema of safari: would open the browser, but then how do you specify https?

Comment: You need to manage the paths that open your app in the `apple-app-site-association` file on `webapp.foo.com` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: Because I didn't provide an answer, just a comment (which probably answered your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `exclude` the relevant path in your `apple-app-site-association` file hosted on your server.

The full documentation is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains)

You will want something like

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "/": "/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL."
               },
               {
                  "/": "/somepath",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /somepath/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link."
               },
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
```

Comment: A problem we experienced after implementing the solution is that the iPhone appears to cache this file and not update it for some time. It's been suggested 10-20 days. 
Apparently it may be re-fetched when the app is reinstalled or updated.

Comment: This is correct. You can use [developer mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) with Xcode builds to bypass Apple's CDN